# NodeMCU and SDS011

Tags: esp8266, sensors, nodemcu, softwareserial

today I connected the SDS011 to NodeMCU. I noticed that this only works when the sensor is connected to the voltage VU. If I connect the sensor to another pin for the voltage, it does not respond.
Why is this so?

If I see it correctly, the reason must be that data is exchanged via RX and TX.

```
#include "SdsDustSensor.h"

int rxPin = 5; //d1
int txPin = 4; //d2
SdsDustSensor sds(rxPin, txPin);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sds.begin();
  sds.setCustomWorkingPeriod(0);

}

void loop(){
PmResult pm = sds.readPm();
  if (pm.isOk()) {
     Serial.println(pm.pm25);
     Serial.println(pm.pm10);
  }

  delay(250);

}
```

Comment: how can anyone know? ... you said nothing about the sketch that you are using

Comment: Share some schematic/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDS011 needs 5 V powering and the VU pin is the 5 V from USB on the NodeMCU development board.